# Entity Framework EDMX designer extensions default values

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, edmx-designer

Have added designer extensions to EDMX designer which allow me to specify additional information I am using with some T4 templates. All working well but I want to assign defaults to some of my properties when the model is first created or udpated. For example, I want to set one of my property values to a certain value for primary keys. Any idea how I can hook into this?

Thanks

Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooking into creation means specifying the default value simply for property backing field or setting it in constructor. Hooking into updating requires logic in property setters - that is usually handled by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I used SQL Server to delete the `DocumentNode` (`hierachyid`) and `DocumentLevel` columns in the `Production.Document` table, then set the `Title` column as the primary key of the table. This seems to have worked... so far.

In SQL Server Object Explorer > Expand the AdventureWorks db to the Production.Document table > Expand Columns folder > RightClick DocumentNode > Click Modify >>> table populates in the query editor > Right click Columns you wish to edit.